# facebook sdk4 android getprofile

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I'm having this trouble: When I try to do the method "Profile.getprofile()"
it returns me null even using ProfileTracker.

Here's my code:

```
 public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener,ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {




//TODO Facebook
ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
final List<String> permisos = new ArrayList<String>();
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> fb = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        // App code
        mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {

            }
        };
        mProfileTracker.startTracking();
        AccessToken token = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile user = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        String name = user.getName();
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Connected "+name , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // App code

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        // App code

    }
};
```

my onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.init_login);

    imgFacebook = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login_img_facebook);
    imgFacebook.setOnClickListener(this);
    permisos.add("user_friends");
    permisos.add("public_profile");
    LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, fb);
}
```

my onClick:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login_img_facebook:
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,permisos);
        break;
    }
}
```

my onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);        
}
```

I Add this to my Manifest:

```
   <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
          android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

By the way I'm using eclipse instead of Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong placement of code

```
AccessToken token = loginResult.getAccessToken();
Profile user = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
String name = user.getName();
Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Connected "+name , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Above code should be placed inside the tracker's function

```
mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
    @Override
    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
        // Place above code here...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked for me, but now I have another doubt... the first time I log in it works fine but after the first time it doesn't appear me the toast :(

Comment: May be due to the fact that your `ProfileTracker` is activated only in `onSuccess()` method of `FacebookCallback` which I don't think is called..
Or, maybe the profile hasn't even changed as you are already logged in.. try getting it directly as well...